# Error No default container found with grails

Tags: tomcat, grails

I try to start a webapp thanks to `grails run-app` command but I've got the following error :

```
| Compiling 8 source files

| Compiling 81 source files.....

| Error No default container found. Please install a container plugin such as 'tomcat' first.
```

BuildConfig.groovy contains build `":tomcat:$grailsVersion"`

I have no idea  about resolving this problem.

Thanks for your help !

EDIT1 : I modified my BuildConfig.groovy and it contains that : http://pastebin.com/7S16HNHY but it did'nt solved my error. 
I create an app with `grails create-app my-project` and It works fine !

Comment: Have you also tried `grails clean` then run-app?

Comment: Yes, I tried "grails clean" but I've got the error "not default container found" with grails run app.

Comment: Which version of Grails do you use?

Comment: This should not be an issue. How does your application.properties file look like? Make sure you do not have any entries for the plugins there. I would go for a grails clean and then grails compile as well.

Comment: You can read the file's content : http://pastebin.com/ziVZBWsv  Do you think I have to install tomcat plugin ?

Comment: No you should not install-plugin. Just adding the entry as you have mentioned, in BuildConfig is enough. Try to create a new app and try to see if the issue is replicated.

Comment: Here is the BuildConfig.groovy content : http://pastebin.com/2h3QnuJ6 Do you see any problem inside ?

Comment: Yes there is **definitely** a problem. Plugin should be declared inside `plugins{....}`.

Comment: Looks like your app is a plugin... didn't you create it through grails create-plugin ... ??

Comment: @Philippe: Thanks for your comment. In my case the problem was that after an IntelliJ IDE update the default RUN action had changed to one of my plugins instead of the main app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future reference, if upgrading to Grails 2.3.7 per the [Release Notes](http://grails.org/2.3.7+Release+Notes):

> **Recommended Tomcat and Hibernate plugin versions**
>
> If you are upgrading from previous versions of Grails 2.3.x and you
>   use the Hibernate and/or Tomcat plugins you will need to update the
>   versions in `BuildConfig`:
>
> ```
> build ':tomcat:7.0.52.1'
> runtime ':hibernate:3.6.10.10' // ':hibernate4:4.3.4.1' for Hibernate 4
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Try removing `{user-home}/.grails/2.2.4/projects/{your-project}`.  You can make a backup of the folder to another directory if you are nervous about losing anything, but everything in the folder should be generated files.  Then execute `run-app` again and see if it fixes your problem.

Also, a great suggestion by Burt Beckwith in Programming Grails is to change the lines in your `BuildConfig.groovy` file from

```
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
```

to

```
grails.project.work.dir = 'target'
```

Then if your project gets into an unrecoverable state, you just blow away the `/target` directory and everything will be regenerated for you.

Answer (score 3):

See [how plugins are declared](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#ivy) in `BuildConfig.groovy`.

You need this section at least:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    inherits("global") {
    }
    repositories {
        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()
    }

    plugins {
        build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"
    }
}
```